# conditional render disappears after a few seconds

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am making a website front end (react) which talks to my back end (npm express/npm mssql)

I have made a page in which it uses a map function to render a separate component containing questions.

I have tried to implement a conditional render so that when question complete is set as true it then renders a new component but the new component will vanish  after a second or so and will go back to its original state.

these are both in the same file so only one set of imports are required in this situation.

This is my display questions class using a .map to render the separate component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

class DisplayQuestions extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { questions: [], QuestionsAnswer: [], QuestionsSeverity: [] };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  getItems() {
    fetch("/user-questions")
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
      });
  }
  //when the component mounts make the sql questions the s
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      questions: this.getItems()
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      QuestionID: this.QuestionID,
      QuestionsAnswer: this.state.QuestionsAnswer,
      QuestionSeverity: this.state.QuestionsSeverity
    };

    try {
      fetch("/Question-Response", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    } catch (error) {}
  }
  refresh() {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  render() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(this.state.questions);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <u>Desk Assessment</u>
        </h3>

        <ul>
          <button
            disabled
            className="btn btn-secondary"
            style={{ float: "left " }}
          >
            Desk Assessment
          </button>




          <Link to="./user-history">
            <button className="btn btn-secondary" style={{ float: "left " }}>
              View History
            </button>
          </Link>
          <br />
          <br />

            {this.state.questions &&
              this.state.questions.map(function(questions, index) {
                return (
                  <div >

                  <ul>
                    <WorkStations questions={questions}></WorkStations>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                );
              })}

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayQuestions;
```

This is my Questions component which is rendered

```
class WorkStations extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = { ...props, show: false, QuestionAnswer: "", QuestionComplete: false };

    this.QuestionDecline = this.QuestionDecline.bind(this);
    this.QuestionOnChange = this.QuestionOnChange.bind(this);
    this.OnCommit = this.OnCommit.bind(this);
  }

  QuestionDecline(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.ShowInput) {
      this.setState({ ShowInput: false });
      alert(this.state.ShowInput);
    } else if (!this.state.ShowInput) {
      this.setState({ ShowInput: true });
      alert(this.state.ShowInput);
    }



  }

  QuestionOnChange(e) {
    this.setState({ QuestionAnswer: e.target.value });
  }


 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// I believe its within here something is off
  OnCommit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.state.QuestionAnswer);

    var today = new Date(),
      date = `${today.getUTCFullYear()}-${today.getUTCMonth() +
        1}-${today.getUTCDate()} ${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}:${today.getSeconds()}.${today.getMilliseconds()} `;

    let User =  window.localStorage.getItem("User")


    const data = {
      QuestionId: this.state.questions.QuestionId,
      QuestionAnswer: this.state.QuestionAnswer,
      date : date,
        User
    };

    fetch("/question-response", {
      method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json,",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(response => {
      console.log("response before it is broken down " + response);

      // return response.json();
    });

      if (this.state.QuestionComplete) {
        this.setState({ QuestionComplete: false });
        alert(this.state.QuestionComplete);
      } else if (!this.state.QuestionComplete) {
        this.setState({ QuestionComplete: true });
        alert(this.state.QuestionComplete);
      }
    window.location.reload();
  }
////////////////////////////////////////////////
  render() {
    if (!this.state.QuestionComplete ){
    if (!this.state.ShowInput && !this.state.QuestionComplete) {
      return (
        <div className="jumbotron">
          <button
            onClick={this.QuestionDecline}
            className="btn btn-danger"
            style={{ float: "right" }}
          >
            Decline
          </button> <button
            onClick={this.deleteQuestion}
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={{ float: "right" }}
          >
            Accept
          </button>

          <br />
          <li> Question ID: {this.state.questions.QuestionId}</li>
          <li> Question:{this.state.questions.Question}</li>
        </div>
      );
    } else if(this.state.ShowInput && !this.state.QuestionComplete) {
      return (
        <div className = "jumbotron">
          <li>Question Id: {this.state.questions.QuestionId}</li>
          <li>
            <textarea
              placeholder= "How can this be improved ?" 
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              onChange={this.QuestionOnChange}
            />
          </li>
          <button
            style={{ float: "right", padding: "2px" }}
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={this.OnCommit}
          >
            Submit
          </button>

          <button
            onClick={this.EditQuestion}
            style={{ float: "right", padding: "2px" }}
            className="btn btn-secondary"
          >
            Revert
          </button>
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    }

    }else if (this.state.QuestionComplete) {
        return(<h3> <li>Question Id: {this.state.questions.QuestionId}</li></h3>)

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: To understand a little better on what's happening. Is your page going blank (nothing displaying?) or is it setting the state to show something else? If it's setting the state and showing something else, what is it showing?

Comment: At the very bottom of the second component I posted there is an else if containing just a question ID and its {this.state.questions.QuestionId}. I want this to display permanently but this vanishes after a second.

Comment: Ah, can you do me a favor in your button when you write `onClick={this.OnCommit}`, change that to `onClick={() => this.OnCommit()}`? Let me know if that helps!

Comment: changes nothing at all sorry

Comment: it is calling the on commit as it does change the component but it vanishes soon. Somehow the state must be modified by something but im not sure what

Comment: From what I can tell from your code, you reload the page once you set the question to completed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207371/discussion-between-tristan-wiley-and-henry-pf).